# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' - Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have this code where I try to assume a role and print Instance IDs:

```
import boto3
account_id = 'accountID'
role_name = 'MyRole'

def assume_role(role_name, account_id):
    session = boto3.Session()
    sts_client = session.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=f'arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/{role_name}',
        RoleSessionName = f'{role_name}-Session'
    )

    assumed_role_credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

    assumed_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=['SessionToken']
    )
    return assumed_session

ec2_role_session = assume_role(role_name, account_id)
instances = ec2_role_session.resource('ec2', region_name="us-east-1").instances.all()

for instance in instances:
    print(f"Instance ID: {instance.id}")
```

But after running using Python 3.7.10 I'm getting following error:

```
return ' '.join(value.split())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I appreciate your guidance!

Comment: That line doesn't appear in the code you show. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Well it's a huge traceback, but this is the first lines: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_ec2.py", line 30, in <module>
    for instance in instances:

Comment: As @Barmar said, you should add the part of the code where the error is, but it seems your `value` is already a list, so there is no need to do a split() on it.

Comment: And if the error is happening inside a library, you're probably passing a list as an argument where a string is expected.

Comment: It seems that you expect `value` to be a string, but it's a list instead.  We can't explain any further, because you have not shown us that code.

Comment: @JohnGordon hmm but this is the only code file I'm using for this. Anyway I'll inspect all the traceback this is giving.

Comment: `aws_session_token=['SessionToken']` Why are you sending a list here?  I think you meant to say `aws_session_token=some_dictionary['SessionToken']` instead, but you forgot the `some_dictionary` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is here

```
assumed_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=['SessionToken']
)
```

In the `aws_session_token` should go `assumed_role_credentials['SessionToken']` as follows:

```
assumed_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=assumed_role_credentials['SessionToken']
)
```

Greetings